# Atom package for capturing keystrokes

Tags: atom-editor

I would like to create an atom package to capture every keystroke and print the inserted/deleted characters in the console along with the line number and position in the line.

I have extended other editors in the past and this info was available as a group of edits. Is there some sample code, a tutorial that shows how to do this, or an example package that does this already?

Answer (score 1):

There is an existing package to count keystrokes, it's in the package library named [keycount](https://atom.io/packages/keycount).  The code for actually detecting and logging the key presses is in the view and works through Atom's event driven API:

```coffee
@disposables.add atom.keymaps.onDidMatchBinding ({keystrokes, binding, keyboardEventTarget}) =>
  @update(keystrokes, binding, keyboardEventTarget)

@disposables.add atom.keymaps.onDidPartiallyMatchBindings ({keystrokes, partiallyMatchedBindings, keyboardEventTarget}) =>
  @updatePartial(keystrokes, partiallyMatchedBindings)

@disposables.add atom.keymaps.onDidFailToMatchBinding ({keystrokes, keyboardEventTarget}) =>
  @update(keystrokes, null, keyboardEventTarget)
```